# problem with PHP server in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I want to run a PHP file as a web page in Eclipse, but every time I try to run it, I get a "404 not found error". I'm using the default PHP Web server in the run configuration. Here's a [screenshot](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/2930/serverconfiguration.jpg) of how I got it configured...
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Well, do you have a web server installed? And at which URL can you see your files?

Answer (score 2):

Troubleshooting:

- Is your webserver running?
- Have you tired access to `localhost` trough your browser? Output?
- Have you tried access to `localhost/First_PHP_Project/newfile.php`? Output?
- Try to remove the slash in the front of **/**`First_PHP_Projcet`
- Do you use any proxies?

Comment: Yes my webserver is running, I've tried accessing the localhost through my browser and I get an "It works!" message. ON the other hand when I tried to access "localhost/First_PHP_Project/newfile.php" I get the follo0wing output:

Not Found
The requested URL /First_PHP_Project/newfile.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

I don't use any proxies.

Comment: @Fez: Then please check the content of your DocumentRoot (e.g: /var/www/)

Comment: There's only one file at that location, it's the html file of the message that I got when I ran the localhost from my browser. Should there be more files in the folder?

Comment: @Fez: If you'd like to run/debug newfile.php, yes, you have to got newfile.php.

Comment: Ok. Is there any way to add the path of my existing eclipse project to the Web Server path?

Comment: @Fez: You could create a symlink ($ man ln) or just remove by refactor your whole project. On dev computer it's ok to work in the DocumentRoot.